# Construir una lista de tuplas a partir de lineas de texto

Tags: map, scala

Estoy intentando formar una estructura a partir de un archivo de texto. Inicio leyendolo como texto en lineas y despues creo una case class de dos elementos donde pretendo introducir las lineas de texto que cumplan un patrón.
Tambien pretendo formar una lista de todos estos case class que va encontrando por medio de una funcion que hace append "funcApend()". Posteriormente dentro de un map empiezo a iterar en las lineas de texto, buscando los que cumplen tal patrón.

```
val ticket = Source.fromFile(inpath).getLines
case class Data(str1: String, str2: String)

def funcAppend(y: List[Data], x: Data): List[Data] ={
   return y :+ x
}
var d1 = Data("")

val brand = ticket.toList.map(x => {
   if(x.contains("TARJETA1")){
      d1 = d1.copy(str1 = x, str2 = "")
      if (d1 != "") {
         d1 = funcAppend(List(d1), Data(x))
         }
      }
   if(x.contains("TARJETA2")){
      d1 = d1.copy(str1= "", str2 = x)
      if (d1 != "") {
         d1 = funcAppend(List(d1), Data(x))
         }
      }
   }
)
```

Pretendo obtener una salida de este tipo:
List(Data("TARJETA1", ""), Data("", "TARJETA2"), Data("TARJETA1", ""), ... )

El error que obtengo del codigo anterior es:

```
Error:(43, 26) type mismatch;
 found   : List[Data]
 required: Data
          d1 = funcAppend(List(d1), Data(x))
```

- Parece que mi entendimiento del funcionamiento de la funcion map() no es del todo completo, pues lo estoy queriendo entender como si fuera un ciclo for tradicional.

Les agradeceria la ayuda
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo creo que te complicas más de lo necesario. Como dices, estás usando `map` como si fuera un `for`, usando **variables**, algo que no cuadra bien con la programación funcional. (Por cierto, a `var d1 = Data("")` le falta un argumento). El `map` es para crear *elementos al vuelo*, algo así:

```scala
val brand = ticket.toList.map(x => {
   if(x.contains("TARJETA1")) {
      Data(x, "")
   else if (x.contains("TARJETA2")){
      Data("", x)
   } else {
      Data("", "")
   }
)
```

Comment: Hola. Te agradezco tu comentario. Es verdad, asi como lo has hecho no es necesario que yo hiciera alguna funcion de append que me estaba complicando todo. Asi como tal, crea la lista de tipos Data.

Answer (score 0):

El error no se da por la funcion map, sino porque `d1` no esta declarada como lista

```
var d1 = Data("") //Aunque deberia ser Data("","") ya que según la declaracion recibe dos parametros
```

pero esta tratando de hacerle una asignacion como si fuera una lista

```
d1 = funcAppend(List(d1), Data(x))
```

deberia declarar d1 como lista así:

```
var d1 = List(Data("")) //Aunque deberia ser List(Data("",""))
```

y pasarle esa lista como primer parámetro a la funcion `funcApend`

```
d1 funcAppend(1, Data(x))
```

En cuando a la forma en la que comprendes la función map te diría que no lo vieras sencillamente como una iteración, sino como un método que se aplica sobre una lista de un tamaño x y produce otra lista de tamaño x donde la lambda que recibe como parametro fabrica un elemento de salida en función de cada elemento de entrada. Internamente itera, pero no es su único potencial, sino la transformación misma de los elementos de entrada. Algebraicamente sería que

Dados

- Un `vector X=(x1,x2, ...,xn)` en un espacio vectorial `A` de dimension `n` con cada elemento `x1,x2, ..., xn` de tipo `T1`
- Una funcion `z = F(x)` donde `x` es de tipo `T1` y es de tipo `T2` (Esta función en el lenguajes de programación se conoce como lambda)

El método map produce un vector `Z=(z1,z2, ... ,zn)` en un espacio vectorial `B` de dimension `n` con cada elemento `z1, z2, ..., zn` de tipo `T2` tal que `z1=F(x1)`, `z2=F(x2)`, ... , `zn = F(xn)`

Comment: Gracias por la explicación del map. Es verdad es una transformación.